# Regarding customizing telerik radEditor skin

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, telerik

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">

<link href="Skins/CustomSkin/Editor.Default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

<telerik:RadEditor ToolbarMode="Default"
ID="editor1" runat="server" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" Skin="CustomSkin">
</telerik:RadEditor>


</asp:Content>
```

RADEditor on my page was inheriting Master Page's CSS properties so followed [this](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/createnewskin.html) tutorial to create custom skin..now what I did was...I simply copied the Folder named "Default" under Skins folder and renamed it to "CustomSkin" and added it like in the code above ..thot it would work but it didn't coz now I don't see border on my RADEditor...why is that ? Also it is STILL inheriting properties from Master page's CSS file :(

I didn't change name of any of the CSS files inside "CustomSkin" folder...Also when I added the following inside "telerik:RadEditor"...still problem persisting..

```
<CssFiles>
       <telerik:EditorCssFile Value="~/Skins/CustomSkin/Editor.Default.css" />
       <telerik:EditorCssFile Value="~/Skins/CustomSkin/Window.Default.css" />
       <telerik:EditorCssFile Value="~/Skins/CustomSkin/ToolBar.Default.css" />
   </CssFiles>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok got it sorted out myself..CSS needed to be linked properly..made some changes in CustomSkin CSS files and marked some properties as !important so it won't inherit from parent page